# Multi input in Django

Tags: python, django, input, upload

How can you pass multiple object IDs into a Django form? Is there a way to pass in a JavaScript Array containing multiple object IDs into a form field and iterate through it on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CommaSeparatedIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield) to store the IDs, perhaps even with a [HiddenInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput) widget if your populating the data dynamically in JavaScript.

You'll be able to iterate through a list of integers from your form's `cleaned_data` after you validate the form on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a new Field and override the 'to_python' method.

The following basic example create a new char field which accept a string containing ids separated by comma and return a query set.

```
class MyField(forms.CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        ids = value.split(',')

        return MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=ids)

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ids = MyField()
```

Have a look at 
[how validation work in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).